# How to check for particular constraint in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have Following model.

```
class BusCompanyStaff(BaseModel):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        BusCompanyUser,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    position = models.ForeignKey(
        StaffPosition,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        related_name='position'
    )
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='created_by'
    )
    staff_of = models.ForeignKey(
        BusCompany,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
```

and my StaffPostion model is

```
class StaffPosition(BaseModel):
    name = TitleCharField(
        max_length=20,
        validators=[validate_staff_position],
        unique=True)

    class Meta:
        default_permissions = ()
        verbose_name = 'Staff Position'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Staff Positions'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Problem is one bus company can only have one staff position 'Owner'  and allow many other staff position i.e 'mamagers, cashiers' but Owner position is set to be unique for particular bus company.
I thought of using **UniqueConstraints** and Unique together but found unique constraint condition can not be indexed i.e It was restricted.

I tried this in clean method.

```
def clean(self):
    if len(BusCompanyStaff.objects.filter(
        position__name='Owner')) > 1:
        raise DjangoValidationError(
            {'position': _('Cannot Assign two owners.')}
        )
```

But above method checked 'Owner' for all bus companies I am not getting how to make Owner as Unique for particular bus company.

Comment: From django documents you can create your own model constraint and validate by the name of your constraint https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/constraints/#

Comment: I mean how can I validate Unique for only owners but not for other staff position?

Comment: you will get the instance of BusCompany before saving right? before save just check if `len(BusCompanyStaff.objects.filter(position__name='Owner', staff_of=BusCompany_instance)) > 1`

Comment: Ok got it but how can I get the 'BusCompany_instance' in model? i.e  in clean method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def clean(self):
    if len(BusCompanyStaff.objects.filter(
        position__name='Owner',
        staff_of=self.staff_of)) > 0:
        raise DjangoValidationError(
            {'position': _('Cannot Assign two owners.')}
        )
```

Comment: This is not working 100% but does not throw error while adding.

Comment: I have edited your ans thank you for ans and validate ans from your side

Answer (score 1):

You can access other field of your form [link to docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/3.1/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other) in clean by super() on clean() method of it:

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super().clean()

    bus_company_id = cleaned_data.get('staff_of') 

    # check more than 1 owner per BusCompany
    if len(BusCompanyStaff.objects.filter(position__name='Owner', staff_of__id=int(bus_company_id)) > 1:
        self.add_error('position','Cannot Assign two owners.')

    return cleaned_data
```